# SMTP routing with EDGE servers for Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2010, smtp, exchange

I am trying to set up some EDGE servers for Exchange 2010 (SP3 UR2) but they are being a real pain.  I have the following servers in my environment:

```
CASHT1 – CAS array member – FQDN is CASHT1.DOMAIN.LOCAL
CASHT2 – CAS array member – FQDN is CASHT2.DOMAIN.LOCAL
MB1 – FQDN is MB2.DOMAIN.LOCAL
MB2 – FQDN is MB2.DOMAIN.LOCAL
```

I am trying to add two EDGE servers in a DMZ (for now they are inside the firewall on the LAN):

```
EDGE1 – FQDN is EDGE1.DOMAIN.LOCAL
EDGE2 – FQDN is EDGE2.DOMAIN.LOCAL
```

I have a split-DNS domain.  Publically we are DOMAIN.COM but internally we are DOMAIN.LOCAL.  Our email addresses are using “USER@DOMAIN.COM” and the EDGE servers are authoritative for the DOMAIN.COM and DOMAIN.LOCAL domains.  My EDGE servers (for now) have complete DNS access and can resolve and ping any internal system successfully.  My EDGE servers are WORKGROUP members.  My other Exchange 2010 systems are all AD members of DOMAIN.LOCAL.  We are only using IPv4 (no IPv6).  The send/receive connectors are all configured properly in Exchange.  The EDGE subscription works properly and everything is synced.  I’ve disabled all of the EDGE server anti-spam features.

When I send a SMTP test to the EDGE servers (either or), the message remains stuck in the queue on the EDGE server reporting a DNS query failure until they eventually time out.  I wasn’t able to figure it out so I put a packet capture on one of the EDGE servers and found that it is making DNS queries asking for an “A” record for DOMAIN.COM.  If I put DOMAIN.COM in the local HOST file and point the IP address to the single CASHT CAS array IP, I get a socket error.  If I point it to either of the IP addresses for the individual CASHT servers LAN NIC, the email goes through successfully.

However, this doesn’t seem right.  If my EDGE servers already report that they are authoritative for the DOMAIN.COM domain, shouldn’t an email to “USER@DOMAIN.COM” be forwarded to either CASHT1 or CASHT2?  Why is the EDGE server looking for an “A” record for DOMAIN.COM (shouldn’t it at least be looking for an internal MX record instead)?  Did I miss something here?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you didn't configure accepted domains on the Edge servers.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124423(v=exchg.141).aspx

As the document says: to check what's configured, type this in EAS

`Get-AcceptedDomain`

Comment: Thanks - seems like that but it isn't.  Both DOMAIN.COM and DOMAIN.LOCAL are authoritative on both of the EDGE servers and DOMAIN.COM is default.  I appreciate the link but unfortunately that doesn't solve the problem.